# Create a breadcrumb of nested lists of categories in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Table

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|      id |   name    | parent_id |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 | Supports  |        0  |    
|       2 | Mobile    |        0  |      
|       3 | Outdoor   |        1  |       
|       4 | Samsung   |        2  |   
|       5 | Cricket   |        3  |  
|       6 | Team A    |        5  |      
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Categories Model

```
class Categories extends Model {

    public $table = "categories";
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'parent_id', 'status'];

    public function parentCat() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function childrenCat() {
        return $this->hasMany(Categories::class, 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

Controller Method

```
Categories::where('parent_id', $parent_id)->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

**Question one**

I want to show a breadcrumb with category and subcategory, if i am viewing cricket subcategories such as:

Home -> Supports -> Outdoor -> Cricket

**Question two**

How to delete all subcategory while deleting main categoriy. Example if i delete Outdoor then Cricket and Team A should be delete

Comment: Where does "Team A" fit into this picture?  It only occurs in the very last sentence as an example which doesn't exactly clarify where this comes from.

Comment: @tripleee Sorry! its updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all think to change your categories structure to the [Nested Set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). It's better and esier to handle nested categories (and ant other structure). Here is nice Laravel's package:

https://github.com/etrepat/baum

For your example there is only not especially optimal solution. When you willl query the leaf category:

```
$category = Categories::where('parent_id', $parent_id)
               ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
               ->first();
return view({your view here}, compact('category'));
```

You'll need partial view (ex.: `breadcrumb.blade.php`) with section:

```
<ul>
@section('breadcrumb')
@show
</ul>
```

The in the main action vie you can do somethink like that:

```
@section('breadcrumb')
    <li>{{$category->name}}</li>
@stop
@while($parent = $category->parent)
    @section('breadcrumb')
        @parent
        <li>{{$parent->name}}</li>
    @stop
@endwhile
```

**ATTENTION**

But as I said in the begining - this is VERY sub-optimal solution because you have to call query for each parent, so it's only fine if you have not much nested levels.